How to do gj or gk multiple times more efficiently?
If I want to move up and down the display lines in normal mode, I have to press gj and gk repeatedly.
Is there a way so I could just press j and k repeatedly and temporarily to do so?

If you use these often, you might want to consider mapping e.g. Ctrl+J and Ctrl+K or Shift+J and Shift+K (uppercase version) or Alt+J and Alt+K to do the display line motions, does that help you?

It should be noted that the uppercase versions will make you lose J to join lines and K to open docs/man pages. Which is fine if you don't use them. I find them very useful.

About the gj topic there is several approaches:

remapping to another key
switching gj and j
use a repeat motion plugin

Remapping to Another Key
Like suggested by @filbranden you could do:
nnoremap <C-j> gj
nnoremap <C-k> gk

Or as suggested by @Friedrich you could do:
nnoremap <Down> gj
nnoremap <Up> gk

The advantage of such mapping is that:

When you use Up and Down Vim behave more like Notepad
When you use k and j Vim behave more like Vim

Switching gj and j
If you swtich gj and j you could simply use j for gj
nnoremap j gj
nnoremap gj j

nnoremap k gk
nnoremap gk k

Using a Motion Repetition Plugin
With vim-remotions you can repeat motions/actions using the , and ; keys.
After hitting gj for the first time you could repeat the motion with ; or perform the reverse action (i.e.: gk) with , and vice and versa.
Provided that you have the following vim-remotions configuration:
let g:remotions_motions = {
    \ 'TtFf' : {},
    \ 'displayline' : {
    \    'backward' : 'gk',
    \    'forward' : 'gj',
    \ },


As a side note: one might consider using the <up> and <down> arrows according to the "another key" solution. This would make the arrow keys behave as in a Notepad-style editor and jk as in vi.
